# Invalid parameter configuration provided for $rulesApplier argument of Magento\\OfflineShipping\\Model\\SalesRule\\Calculator Magento 2

Tags: parameters, arguments, magento2

I got this error when i rewrite SalesRule module for RulesApplier Class to custom module to adding extra validation before rule apply using applyRules().

My di.xml

```
  <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="rulesApplier" xsi:type="array">Custom\SalesRule\Model\RulesApplier</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

My Class

```
namespace Custom\SalesRule\Model;

use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\CalculatorFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Utility;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\ChildrenValidationLocator;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\DataFactory;
use Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleDiscountInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\DiscountDataInterfaceFactory;


class RulesApplier extends \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RulesApplier 
{

/**
 * custom validation before applying rule
 * 
 * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\CalculatorFactory\CalculatorFactory $calculatorFactory
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
 * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Utility $utility
 * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Quote\ChildrenValidationLocator|null $childrenValidationLocator
 * @param DataFactory|null $discountDataFactory
 * @param RuleDiscountInterfaceFactory|null $discountInterfaceFactory
 * @param DiscountDataInterfaceFactory|null $discountDataInterfaceFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    CalculatorFactory $calculatorFactory, 
    ManagerInterface $eventManager, 
    Utility $utility, 
    ChildrenValidationLocator $childrenValidationLocator = null,
    DataFactory $discountDataFactory = null,
    RuleDiscountInterfaceFactory $discountInterfaceFactory = null,
    DiscountDataInterfaceFactory $discountDataInterfaceFactory = null
) {
    parent::_construct(
        $calculatorFactory, 
        $eventManager, 
        $utility, 
        $childrenValidationLocator,
        $discountDataFactory,
        $discountInterfaceFactory,
        $discountDataInterfaceFactory
    );
}

/**
 * Apply rules to current order item
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item
 * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection $rules
 * @param bool $skipValidation
 * @param mixed $couponCode
 * @return array
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
*/
public function applyRules($item, $rules, $skipValidation, $couponCode) 
{
    $address = $item->getAddress();
    $appliedRuleIds = [];
    /* @var $rule \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule */
    foreach ($rules as $rule) {
        if (!$this->validatorUtility->canProcessRule($rule, $address)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!$skipValidation && !$rule->getActions()->validate($item)) {
            if (!$this->childrenValidationLocator->isChildrenValidationRequired($item)) {
                continue;
            }
            $childItems = $item->getChildren();
            $isContinue = true;
            if (!empty($childItems)) {
                foreach ($childItems as $childItem) {
                    if ($rule->getActions()->validate($childItem)) {
                        $isContinue = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($isContinue) {
                continue;
            }
        }

        $this->applyRule($item, $rule, $address, $couponCode);
        $appliedRuleIds[$rule->getRuleId()] = $rule->getRuleId();

        if ($rule->getStopRulesProcessing()) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return $appliedRuleIds;
}
```

actually, i want to validate with my custom validation like rule applying limit qty to the cart items how many products can apply on cart,

Let suppose customer added 5 product into cart and admin allowed to discount only 3 per customer by coupon, so i need to add my custom efforts to apply coupon only 3 minimum price items.

can anyone guide me where i am wrong.

Thanks
Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 1):

After a deep search into arguments finaly understand the issue resolved by a small change in posted code.

Replace xsi:type="array" By xsi:type="object" because injected argument is a class object not an array.

Replace

```
<argument name="rulesApplier" xsi:type="array">Custom\SalesRule\Model\RulesApplier</argument>
```

By

```
 <argument name="rulesApplier" xsi:type="object">Custom\SalesRule\Model\RulesApplier</argument>
```

Hope this will help to you guys !!

Happy Coding